# Move files from Remote Server to another Remote Server

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to move files from one remote server to another remote server
I have this batch file code which only work on the same server:

```
move /y "F:\Folder 1\*.asp" "F:\Folder 3"
```

Now, I want to try to move files to another remote server using this code (sample ip address only)

```
move /y "F:\Folder 1\*.asp" "100.50.0.0\Folder 3"
```

I'm getting "invalid drive specification" message in cmd.

Please let me know if I'm missing something or there's another way.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with my codes, I came up with this solution:

```
move /y "F:\Folder 1\*.asp" "\\100.50.0.0\F$\Folder 3\"
```

and it worked!

Hope this also helps others.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify server UNC path like below

```
move /y "\\ServerA\F:\Folder 1\*.asp" "\\ServerB\F$\Folder 3"
```

In case this doesn't work, you may consider doing a `XCOPY` instead like

```
xcopy "\\ServerA\F:\Folder 1\*.asp" "\\ServerB\F$\Folder 3" /s/e/h
```

Comment: the 1st one should have F$ on the second parameter to work :)
Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @carl, Yes exactly since it's a remote server. Thanks for pointing. Edited answer.